# rails 3 show from related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my events_controller, if I use the following:

```
def index
    respond_with(@market.events) do |format|
        format.js {render :json => @market.events, :callback => params[:callback]}
    end
end
```

I get the expected response. Events is a nested resource under markets.
But I need to also return the asset associated with the event, which is in a related table. If I try the following:

```
respond_with(@market.events.joins @market.events.assets) do |format|
```

I get undefined method `assets' for #ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1088215a0. On my events show page, I can do asset.asset.url and it shows.

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple events, and you're trying to call `assets` on the *collection* of events—that is, a set of many events, which doesn't have `assets`, though each element in the collection has `assets`.

You say you want to get the asset (singular) for the event (also singular), so I'm not really sure what you actually want to achieve here, since you're returning multiple assets. To get all the assets for all the events you can do:

```
@market.events.map(&:assets).flatten # If event has many assets
@market.events.map(&:asset)          # If event has one asset
```

Comment: render :json => @market.events.map(&:assets).flatten works. I was putting it in respond with method at first till your explanation of the collection sunk in. Thanks, Andrew

Comment: bummer. I looked again, and although it's returning the assets, the event data is gone :(

Comment: render :json => @market.events + @market.events.map(&:assets).flatten returns a fairly ugly json object, but I should be able to parse through it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried eager loading ? With `@market.events.includes(:assets)`, you should have the assets too.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that `@market.events` does not respond to `assets`.

Comment: `@market.events` is a collection. The members will respond to `assets`, as in `@market.events.first.assets`. You can iterate over it after.

Comment: if I use &:assets, the error goes away, but no data returned from the assets table.